# How to make an equation to get the sum of all previous numbers of an equation?

Tags: exponential-function

Given an equation of an exponential line how would I get the sum of all previous whole numbers in that line down to 0.

For example.
With the equation:
$y = 100 \times 1.3 ^x$

How would I create another equation to get the sum of all previous values given x?

for example, an equation that would get me this sum column.

```
|---x---|100 * 1.3 ^ x|--sum--|
------------------------------
|---0---|-----100-----|--100--|
|---1---|-----130-----|--230--|
|---2---|-----169-----|--399--|
|---3---|-----220-----|--619--|
```

I've searched and found triangle numbers (x<sup>2</sup> + x)/2 which is almost what  I'm searching for but have failed to find a way to implement this using an equation.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^x(ab^k)=a\,\frac{b^{x+1}-1}{b-1}\qquad (b\ne1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to compute the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 100 a^k$$

For $a=1.3$

Then, for any $a\neq1$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 100 a^k=100\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=100\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$

Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that wiki link pointed me in the right direction. I feel the ending formula was meant to be $$\sum_{k=0}^n 100 a^k=100\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=100\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$

Comment: Sorry meant to type a new line not submit $$\sum_{k=0}^n 100 a^k=100\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=100\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$

Comment: Sorr this one: $$\sum_{k=0}^n 100 a^k=100\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=100\frac{1 - a^{n+1}}{1 - a}$$

Comment: @Jafer Multiply by $-1$ in denominator and numerator: it's the same formula